# VIsual Studio says that I have error in the string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int temp;
    string phase;
    cout << "the temperature is: ";
    cin >> temp;

    if (temp > 0 && temp < 100) {
        phase = "liquid";

    }
    else if (temp < 0)
        phase = "ice";
    else
        phase = "gas";

    cout << "the phase is :" << phase << endl; 


    return 0;
}
```

I write C++ and I have can't display the variable phase . This also stops the compiler and I can't compile it.

Comment: Please provide the full error message and indicate where it occurs.

Comment: Change `#include "stdafx.h"` to `#include <string>`

Comment: You to '#include <string>'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q66fVanY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int temp;
    string phase;
    cout << "the temperature is: ";
    cin >> temp;

    if (temp > 0 && temp < 100) {
        phase = "liquid";

    }
    else if (temp < 0)
        phase = "ice";
    else
        phase = "gas";

    cout << "the phase is :" << phase << endl; 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.